# How to find the definition of a OpenCV class?

Tags: opencv

For example, I want to find the definition of class `Matx` in module `core`.

The file tree of module `core` is as follows:

```
|-module
  |-core
    |-doc
    |-include
      |-core.hpp
    |-perf
    |-src
    |-test
    |-CMakeLists.txt
```

I can find the declaration of `Matx` in `core.hpp`, but cannot find the definition of class `Matx` by searching all the files in `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is defined in the matx.hpp which can be found here:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp

specifically after the line:

```
    ////////////////////////////////// Matx Implementation ///////////////////////////////////
```

This will follow the same pattern for the rest of the OpenCV code.